# Multiple input field file upload in S3 using Laravel8

Tags: amazon-s3, laravel-8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ezNn.png)

Please see the picture I have multiple input fields for file upload in AWS S3. Every input field creates its own folder and store image in S3 like Poster / Key Artwork and Poster (Quad) ... etc

Please check this code I have written.1st input field creates its own folder ( poster_art ) on s3  and stores the image but 2nd one is not working. Please help me if someone knows how to do this.
I will be very thankful to you.

```
public function storemultipleImages(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, ['image' => 'required|image']);
    if ($request->hasfile('image')) {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $filePath = 'poster_art/' . $name;
        Storage::disk('s3')->put($filePath, file_get_contents($file));
        return back()->with('success', 'Image Uploaded successfully');
     }

     $this->validate($request, ['image' => 'image']);
     if ($request->hasfile('image')) {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $filePath = 'poster_quad/' . $name;
        Storage::disk('s3')->put($filePath, file_get_contents($file));
        return back()->with('success', 'Image Uploaded successfully');
     } 

}
```

Comment: Please use a debugger to inspect the content of your request parameter

Comment: @sylvain Thank you so much for your reply my issue has been fixed.